# Regex to remove blank lines, unless multi-line is present

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I'm looking for help to allow my users to shrink the formatting of some text output, to fit their preference.

Example:

```
User list Summary:


Title:
- Big Pink

Student:
- Philip J Fry

Grade:
- A

Issues:
- This issue
- That issue

Improvements:
- This thing
- That thing
- The other thing
```

Id like to be able to shorten single answers to one line, but leave multi-line answers alone. So that the above becomes:

```
User list Summary:

Title: Big Pink
Student: Philip J Fry
Grade: A
Issues:
- This issue
- That issue
Improvements:
- This thing
- That thing
- The other thing
```

I've got this far: https://jsfiddle.net/hematogones/0d4g0akh/

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you familiar with the awesome utility of regex101.com?

Comment: So `Improvements: this thing` when only 1 `-this thing` ?

Comment: @Pytth Thanks - I didn't know about that site. I've been trying it out and it really is a great resource for learning regex. I've been using Regexr, but Regex101 has more granular explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this, using negative look-ahead to make sure you only collapse a hyphenated line after a colon when no other is following it:

```
text.replace(/:\r?\n-\h*(.*)$(?!\r?\n-)/gm, ": $1" ).replace(/^\s*\r?\n/gm,'');
```

```js
const text = $("#outPut").val();
$(".switch").on("click", function(){ 
    var text_new = "";
    if (this.id == "switchto"){
        text_new = text.replace(/:\r?\n-\h*(.*)$(?!\r?\n-)/gm, ": $1" ).replace(/^\s*\r?\n/gm,'');
        $("#outPut").val(text_new);
    }
    if (this.id == "switchback"){
        $("#outPut").val(text);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="outPut" style="width:60%; min-height:180px">
User list Summary:


Title:
- Big Pink

Student:
- Philip J Fry

Grade:
- A

Issues:
- This issue
- That issue

Improvements:
- This thing
- That thing
- The other thing

+ Final score:
- 78%

</textarea>
<br>
<input type="button" class="switch" id="switchto" value="Switch synoptic">
<input type="button" class="switch" id="switchback" value="Switch back">
```

Comment: I'm shocked JS knows horizontal whitespace `\h`

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know that either!

Comment: What does $1 do in the replace syntax?

Comment: `$1` repeats what was matched in the parentheses: that part should not be deleted.